# Getting embeddings of length 1 from Langchain OpenAIEmbeddings

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I'm trying to use Langchain to create a vectorstore from scraped HTML pages, but I encountered an issue where I'm getting embeddings of length 1 when it should be 1536 per https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings.

Here's how my code looks:

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import BSHTMLLoader
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS

...

all_raw_documents = []

for file in html_files:
    loader = BSHTMLLoader(file)
    raw_documents = loader.load()
    all_raw_documents.extend(raw_documents)

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=1000,
    chunk_overlap=200,
)
documents = text_splitter.split_documents(all_raw_documents)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
```

On the last line, I'm getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ingest.py", line 128, in <module>
    ingest_docs(customers)
  File "/ingest.py", line 34, in ingest_docs
    vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/base.py", line 272, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(texts, embedding, metadatas=metadatas, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/faiss.py", line 385, in from_texts
    return cls.__from(
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/faiss.py", line 348, in __from
    index.add(np.array(embeddings, dtype=np.float32))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (13238,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

After some investigation, I found that the problem is due to getting the following erroneous embeddings:

```json
{
  "embedding": [
    NaN
  ],
  "index": 520,
  "object": "embedding"
}
```

As you can see, the embedding returned has length 1 instead of a real embedding with length 1536.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now we had to update `/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/embeddings/openai.py` directly to retry embedding generation for the erroneous chunk inside `_get_len_safe_embeddings()`.

Edit: Code

```py
def _get_len_safe_embeddings(
    self, texts: List[str], *, engine: str, chunk_size: Optional[int] = None
) -> List[List[float]]:
    embeddings: List[List[float]] = [[] for _ in range(len(texts))]
    try:
        import tiktoken
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError(
            "Could not import tiktoken python package. "
            "This is needed in order to for OpenAIEmbeddings. "
            "Please install it with `pip install tiktoken`."
        )

    tokens = []
    indices = []
    encoding = tiktoken.model.encoding_for_model(self.model)
    for i, text in enumerate(texts):
        if self.model.endswith("001"):
            # See: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/418#issuecomment-1525939500
            # replace newlines, which can negatively affect performance.
            text = text.replace("\n", " ")
        token = encoding.encode(
            text,
            allowed_special=self.allowed_special,
            disallowed_special=self.disallowed_special,
        )
        for j in range(0, len(token), self.embedding_ctx_length):
            tokens += [token[j : j + self.embedding_ctx_length]]
            indices += [i]

    batched_embeddings = []
    _chunk_size = chunk_size or self.chunk_size
    for i in range(0, len(tokens), _chunk_size):
        print(f"Embedding chunk {i} to {i + _chunk_size}.")
        first_response = embed_with_retry(
            self,
            input=tokens[i : i + _chunk_size],
            **self._invocation_params,
        ) 
        to_retry = [(tokens[i], i) for i in range(len(first_response["data"])) if len(first_response["data"][i]["embedding"]) < 1536]
        print(f"Found {len(to_retry)} errors.")
        attempt = 0
        while len(to_retry) > 0:
            attempt += 1
            cur_token, idx = to_retry[-1]
            response = embed_with_retry(
                self,
                input=[cur_token],
                **self._invocation_params,
            )
            if len(response["data"][0]["embedding"]) == 1536:
                print(f"Replacing embedding for chunk {idx}.")
                first_response["data"][idx]["embedding"] = response["data"][0]["embedding"]
                to_retry.pop()
        batched_embeddings += [r["embedding"] for r in first_response["data"]]
        print(f"Finished embedding chunk {i} to {i + _chunk_size} in {attempt} attempts.")

    print("Finished embedding.")

    results: List[List[List[float]]] = [[] for _ in range(len(texts))]
    num_tokens_in_batch: List[List[int]] = [[] for _ in range(len(texts))]
    for i in range(len(indices)):
        results[indices[i]].append(batched_embeddings[i])
        num_tokens_in_batch[indices[i]].append(len(tokens[i]))

    for i in range(len(texts)):
        _result = results[i]
        if len(_result) == 0:
            average = embed_with_retry(
                self,
                input="",
                **self._invocation_params,
            )[
                "data"
            ][0]["embedding"]
        else:
            average = np.average(_result, axis=0, weights=num_tokens_in_batch[i])
        embeddings[i] = (average / np.linalg.norm(average)).tolist()

    return embeddings
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please add your code to make a clearer answer for people who will encounter the same problem